# How to extract efficientely <![CDATA[]> content from an xml with python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, pandas, lxml

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><author id="user23">
    <document><![CDATA["@username: That boner came at the wrong time ???? http://t.co/5X34233gDyCaCjR" HELP I'M DYING       ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[Ugh      ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[YES !!!! WE GO FOR IT. http://t.co/fiI23324E83b0Rt       ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[@username Shout out to me????        ]]></document>
</author>
```

What is the most efficient way to parse and extract the `<![CDATA[`content`]]>` into a list. Let's say:

```
[@username: That boner came at the wrong time ???? http://t.co/5X34233gDyCaCjR" HELP I'M DYING      Ugh     YES !!!! WE GO FOR IT. http://t.co/fiI23324E83b0Rt      @username Shout out to me????       ]
```

This is what I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
x='/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TratandoDeMejorarPAN/test.xml'
y = BeautifulSoup(open(x), 'xml')
out = [y.author.document]
print out
```

And this is the output:

```
[<document>"@username: That boner came at the wrong time ???? http://t.co/5XgDyCaCjR" HELP I'M DYING        </document>]
```

The problem with this output is that I should not get the `<document></document>`. How can I remove the `<document></document>` tags and get all the elements of this xml in a list?.

Comment: Modern BeautifulSoup already uses lxml under-the-hood. Anyhow -- can you quantify what you mean by "efficiently"?

Comment: ...that said -- `CDATA` doesn't create separate elements at all -- it's just a syntactic sugar for escaping text. Thus, you'd want to read that text straight out of the `document`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the feed. By efficiently I refer as quickly, since I have a lot of big xmls like this.

Comment: So, CPU performance only, with no regard to memory usage?

Comment: ...and now you're asking about an error, not about performance. Pick one or the other.

Comment: By now only CPU performance, thanks @CharlesDuffy

Comment: You need to [explicitly specify that you’re parsing XML](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id17) using `BeautifulSoup(x, "xml")`.

Comment: Sure @CharlesDuffy I dont know if BeautifulSoup is the correct way to aproach this.

Comment: Did you actually _read_ the warning you got, where it tells you to pass a file object and not a filename string?

Comment: By the way -- you might want to consider sanitizing your data's contents.

Comment: It is a corpus, I am doing some NLP task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things wrong here. (Asking questions on selecting a library is against the rules here, so I'm ignoring that part of the question).

1. You need to pass in a file *handle*, not a file *name*.

   That is: `y = BeautifulSoup(open(x))`
2. You need to tell BeautifulSoup that it's dealing with XML.

   That is: `y = BeautifulSoup(open(x), 'xml')`
3. `CDATA` sections don't create elements. You can't search for them in the DOM, because they don't exist in the DOM; they're just syntactic sugar. Just look at the text directly under the `document`, don't try to search for something named `CDATA`.

   To state it again, somewhat differently: `<doc><![CDATA[foo]]</doc>` is **exactly the same** as `<doc>foo</doc>`. What's different about a `CDATA` section is that everything inside it is automatically escaped, meaning that `<![CDATA[<hello>]]` is interpreted as `&lt;hello&gt;`. However -- you can't tell from the parsed object tree whether your document contained a `CDATA` section with literal `<` and `>` or a raw text section with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. This is by design, and true of any compliant XML DOM implementation.

---

Now, how about some code that actually works:

```
import bs4

doc="""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><author id="user23">
    <document><![CDATA["@username: That came at the wrong time ????" HELP I'M DYING       ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[Ugh      ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[YES !!!! WE GO FOR IT.       ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[@username Shout out to me????        ]]></document>
</author>
"""

doc_el = bs4.BeautifulSoup(doc, 'xml')
print [ el.text for el in doc_el.findAll('document') ]
```

If you want to read from a file, replace `doc` with `open(filename, 'r')`.

Comment: I dont get what happened here: `user_content = [ el.text for el in doc_el.findAll('document') ]` could you provide some explanation?. Why text and how `.findAll`was used?

Comment: From `help(el)`, under "Data descriptors inherited from bs4.element.Tag", see: "text - Get all child strings, concatenated using the given separator."

Comment: So the trick to this is that you are telling BeautifulSoup to parse the data as XML and then it works and you can pull in the CDATA information. It will NOT work if you are using LXML which is what most of the tutorials are having you use. I had some working code already so I created a new object using XML and was able to get it to show me the comments. `comment_content = bs(content,"xml") 
for el in comment_content.findAll('txt'): 
print ('COMMENT -> ', el.text )`